# ActiveRecord + Oracle connectivity issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, activerecord, installation

I did all the installation, perhaps not sure if still missing some thing.

I want Rails with Oracle. What I did is install the `oci8` from RubyForge. And then ActiveRecord enhanced version of Oracle. When I did go to `rake db:create` it alter to install the active record oracle enhance version. Which I did again (`gem install`) and than run `rake db:create` but got same error again. Not sure, what could be the fix.

======================================================================

Following is image of database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  database: //localhost:1521/dba
  username: re*********
  password: ********
```

For active record installation, following is the result set

```
E:\railstest\script>gem install activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter
WARNING:  Error fetching data: SocketError: getaddrinfo: The storage control bl
cks were destroyed.  (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
Successfully installed activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1...
```

When execute localhost:3000/greetings/hello

this is the full trace of error **ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished**

```
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__31549393__call__4__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `send'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
E:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
E:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
E:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
E:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
E:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
E:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
E:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
E:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
E:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
E:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:55
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:50
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Creating an Oracle DB via Rake is a pain.  It needs to have system or a DBA account that can create the user.  That requires setting your DBA password in `database.yml`.  In my opinion this is a bad practice and should be avoided.  Create the DB by hand.
2. Make sure your `database.yml` has the correct adapter declared:

   ```
   adapter:  oracle_enhanced
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Your database definition in the yml seems wrong to me...
You schould give the name you gave in the tnsnames (of your oracle client)